# What happens in a "sleep" in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, kernel, cpu, cpu-architecture

I read that it does not consume CPU cycles but what happens to the program/thread in memory that called the "sleep"? Would it be put into the wait queue? Or what happens? How would the code be translated to machine instructions? Or rather what would be its machine instruction equivalent.

Lets take this example,

```
`#include<WinBase.h>
main()
{
    Sleep(10);
}`
```

This sample is for Windows, but I am meaning to ask this question irrespective of the platform.

Comment: Obviously yes, it is put into some wait queue. The call usually ends up into a system call that put the process into a queue of non electable processes 'til some event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is obviously operating system and processor specific.
I don't know Windows, and since it is [proprietary software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software), many implementation details are hidden by MicroSoft.

So let's consider a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) implementation like Linux. So you can study the source code.

A call to [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) is probably executed (by your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)) as some [*system call*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).

<sup>On Linux, you can use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to see what system calls get executed by some given process or command.</sup>

Any system calls involve (by definition) the operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29). a user-[mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes) to kernel-mode switching machine instruction gets executed (e.g. `SYSENTER` on x86-64, or `INT`, or some call gate, etc...). So the kernel takes control, and its [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) is likely to run *another* runnable [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (on its wait queue, as you guessed), or to [*idle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_%28CPU%29) the processor (if there is no runnable processes). Much later, the kernel will reschedule your process (probably after having handled many [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)).

If you want more details (for Linux!), look into the source code of your libc (e.g. [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) and of the [kernel](http://kernel.org/) itself.

Of course the details are very complex, and you'll need to read many books and study a lot of source code.

You could also read a good textbook like [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). It has *several* chapters on scheduling, processes, and threads.

<sup>(I don't know Windows, but I heard that the actual set of its system calls is not published. You'll code against the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API), and how exactly it is implemented could be some MicroSoft "secret". Hence, I recommend using & installing Linux -or some other free software operating system- if you are interested in understanding the *internals*).</sup>